# Why does a conducting cylinder spin when held next to a conducting ring around a solenoid?

Tags: electromagnetism, education, inductance

My uncle showed me this [video](https://youtu.be/OI_HFnNTfyU?t=487).

I understand that the magnetic field from the solenoid induces a current perpendicular to it in the ring. However, I don't see why this current would result in a torque about the longitudinal axis of the brass cylinder.

My guess is that the magnetic field from the ring is less uniform than that of the solenoid, which somehow results in a torque in the cylinder. Can anyone explain how this actually happens?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you've got the right idea. If you understand why the metal ring levitates due to the ac magnetic field of the solenoid (i.e., induced currents and Lenz's law), and you recognize the fact that the (ac) magnetic field outside the ring is non-uniform and diminishes in intensity with distance, then you should be able to see why there is a torque on the cylinder and why it turns in the direction that it does. Parts of the cylinder which are closer to the ring feel a large force in the upward direction due to electrical currents induced in metal cylinder by the ac magnetic field. Parts of the cylinder further away from the ring also feel an upward force, but it will be smaller due to the slightly greater distance from the ring. The result will be a net non-zero torque on the cylinder which will spin the cylinder as shown in the video.

Comment: Ok I think I can visualize it now. Thanks!